# How do I fix Content Security Policy bugs?

Tags: html, content-security-policy

I have a CSP meta tag that looks like so:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
content="font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:;
 img-src 'self' data:;
 style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:;
 script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' data:;
 default-src 'self' localhost:*">
```

And I have a local JavaScript file reference inside the body tags:

```
   <script src="js/video.min.js"></script>
```

And a local stylesheet file reference in the header tag:

```
<link href="css/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

However, I'm getting the following errors in my browser refusing to load the script or a font from the CSS file.

> Refused to load the script 'https://localhost:44356/js/video.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' data:". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

> 2testvideo.html:1 Refused to load the font 'data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GRgABAAAAABDkAAsAAAAAG6gAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABHU1VCAAABCAAAADsAAABUIIslek9TLzIAAAFEAAAAPgAAAFZRiV3hY21hcAAAAYQAAADaAAADPv749/pnbHlmAAACYAAAC3AAABHQZg6OcWhlYWQAAA3QAAAAKwAAADYZw251aGhlYQAADfwAAAAdAAAAJA+RCLFobXR4AAAOHAAAABMAAACM744AAGxvY2EAAA4wAAAASAAAAEhF6kqubWF4cAAADngAAAAfAAAAIAE0AIFuYW1lAAAOmAAAASUAAAIK1cf1oHBvc3QAAA/AAAABJAAAAdPExYuNeJxjYGRgYOBiMGCwY2BycfMJYeDLSSzJY5BiYGGAAJA8MpsxJzM9kYEDxgPKsYBpDiBmg4gCACY7BUgAeJxjYGS7wTiBgZWBgaWQ5RkDA8MvCM0...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' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src *".

The first script doesn't violate the Content Security Policy as far as I can tell and there isn't any documentation describing 'script-src-elem' anywhere I can find (this may be a clue).

As far as the font in the CSS, there's appears to be a bug in the browsers as there was no CSP directive that looks like "font-src *" - so, somehow the browser is overriding this CSP (or it's just a bug).
Regardless, been hair pulling trying all sorts of combinations (I can't put 'self' in the script-src, for example or more errors show up). It doesn't make any sense!

Here's the complete HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:; img-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:; script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' data:; default-src 'self' localhost:*">
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <video id='my-video' class='video-js' controls preload='auto' width='640' height='360'
           poster='/videos/Factory_Clearance30_03_16.jpg' data-setup='{}'>
        <source src="/videos/Factory_Clearance30_03_16.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="/videos/Factory_Clearance30_03_16.ogv" type="video/ogg">
        <source src="/videos/Factory_Clearance30_03_16.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <script src="js/video.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not for me. I've found a dozen or more references, not one was this inclusive or thorough. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

> The first script doesn't violate the Content Security Policy

The policy says:

> ```
> script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' data:;
> ```

You load the script with:

> ```
> <script src="js/video.min.js"></script>
> ```

So, let's check each in turn:

- Is it `unsafe-eval`? No, you aren't using `eval()` or anything similar to load the script. It is a `src` attribute.
- Is it `unsafe-inline`? No, it isn't inline; it's a `src` attribute.
- Is it `data:`? No. It's a relative URL and you can't be relative to a data: scheme URL. You're probably using `http:`.

So it definitely **does** violate the CSP.

Likely you want to add `'self'` to the allowed origins.

---

> As far as the font in the CSS, there's appears to be a bug in the browsers as there was no CSP directive that looks like "font-src *" - so, somehow the browser is overriding this CSP (or it's just a bug).

The most likely explanation for this is that you are providing a CSP via HTTP headers **and** `<meta>` and the HTTP headers are given priority (because the specification requires that).

Comment: Parts of the script is calling parts that use eval -- so that is necessary.
Parts of the script is also creating elements with inline script (I didn't write these scripts), so that is necessary
Parts of the script are using data base64 (also being utilized by elements generated inside the script), so the data: specifier is needed.
Using 'self' does not work at all for this script (it generates a slew of violations) and does not seem to play nice with the other specifiers.

Comment: The HTTP headers must be overridden elsewhere.  this is dotnetcore - i didn't consider that it may be black boxing something i didn't ask for. (overridding)

Comment: The more "freedom" I add to the CSP, the worse it gets. Now Chrome on one line claims that worker-src was not explicitly set  immediately followed by an error on the next line saying it violates the worker-src directive. (so which is it? not set? or in violation?).  
So it's clear certain parts are overridding other parts (browser, http headers, etc). Frankly, at this point I want everything served from my server allowed (don't care what it does). It's safe

Comment: In a nutshell: HTTP headers overrides META tag declarations, not the other way around? (and Chrome seems to have trouble deciding which to accept)

Comment: Note: If you *are* sending CSP via both HTTP headers and `<meta>` tag, be aware that later CSP can only tighten earlier policies, not loosen.  If you deny X, you can't later allow X; it just doesn't work.. This is by design.

Comment: "Frankly, at this point I want everything served from my server allowed (don't care what it does). It's safe". That belief is how people get hacked.  However, if you really want to allow everything, why not simply NOT send CSP headers at all?

Comment: This is for an application where not sending CSP headers breaks another part (usually a widget/plugin that is precompiled).