# 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script

Tags: javascript, html, css

> Error: Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".

The error only shows in other browser and not chrome. I found some answers and they say to add

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:; img-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:; script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' data:; default-src 'self' localhost:*">
```

**Reference:** [Content Security Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57304848/how-do-i-fix-content-security-policy-bugs)

And after adding the meta tag an error pops up on refresh of the browser including chrome.

> Error: Refused to load the script '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' data:". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

Please help.

Comment: Why do you need to set that meta tag? I believe it's generally used rarely.

Comment: Its giving me the error without using it. The first error is what I get without setting the meta tag.

Comment: You should only enable `unsafe-eval` if it is absolutely necessary, which in most cases, it is not. You should audit your dependencies to find out which one is trying to use eval and replace it with something safer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.
The problem was with **helmet** node module.
When I remove the **app.use(helmet())** from my backend, The problem goes away.

If you're also having this error, I replaced the **app.use(helmet())** with **app.use(
helmet({
contentSecurityPolicy: false,
})
);**

Comment: Also, before disabling. Keep in mind the helmet module is there to prevent attacks and CSP is an added layer of security that helps to detect and mitigate certain types of attacks, XSS and data injection attacks. These attacks are used for everything from data theft, to site defacement, to malware distribution